# How to add multiple Text to asp:label control?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I currently have an asp label that has text pull from a string file. I want to add a red * next to this label. How would I go about doing this?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, sample_generalinformation %>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following. Just add a `span` tag to the right of your label tag, with a style attribute with the value of `color: red`

Like this:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, sample_generalinformation %>"/><span style="color:red;">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `*` along with the same text than this should work:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, sample_generalinformation %> <span style='color: red;'>*</span>"/>
```

Else if you want in seperaret than there is another option of doing it:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, sample_generalinformation %>"/><span style="color:red;">*</span>
```